# Expression in Textbox not passing value to the table

Tags: ms-access

Obviously I am not an Access expert or I would not be asking this question. I created a small database with several tables. On a form, there are several combo boxes for the user to choose different combinations of medium, paper, sizes, etc. I have already created an expression that returns the correct value I need, but I cannot figure out how to get this value into the correct field on the table to store with the record the form is creating. Below are screen shots of the form and a couple of the tables. I have also included the expression I am using. I need the value that the expression returns to go into tbl1Artwork and populate the ArtWorkSKU field.

Expression:
=Left([PieceName],4) & [cbxArtist].Column & [cbxMedium].Column & [cbxPaperType].Column & [cbxPrintType].Column & [cbxSize].Column

The ArtWorkSKU text box is unbound as I had to type the expression in there. I am not sure if this is the correct way to accomplish the goal. In the tables below, except for the PK, all fields are Short Text.

All guidance is greatly appreciated.

[image: ArtWork Form][image: Medium Table][image: PaperType Table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the following function in VBA:

```
Function UpdateSKU() 
Me.ArtWorkSKU = Left(Me.[PieceName],4) & Me.[cbxArtist].Column(3) & _ 
Me.[cbxMedium].Column(2) & Me.[cbxPaperType].Column(2) & _ 
Me.[cbxPrintType].Column(2) & Me.[cbxSize].Column(2) 
End Function
```

Then, on the form, update the After Update event property (not vba) of each "feeder" control to: 
After Update: =UpdateSKU()

Answer (score 0):

Saving calculated data is usually not necessary and can be risky. Saved value can become 'out of sync' with raw data. Value can be calculated when needed.

Saving calculated data requires code (macro or VBA).
Can be as simple as `Me!fieldname = Me.controlname`.

Real trick is figuring out what event(s) to put code into. In your case, most likely form BeforeUpdate.

Advise not to use spaces nor punctuation/special characters (underscore only exception) in naming convention. Better would be ArtworkSKU or ArtworkSKUnum or Artwork_SKU_Num.

Comment: In the end I am trying to concatenate the SKU numbers from different tables based on the user choices on the form and add the new concatenated SKU number into the ArtWorkSKU field on the tbl1Artwork.

Comment: There are no special characters except in the text label. I am still unsure how to get this to work. I am not familiar enough with Access to fully understand your answer.

Comment: What exactly do you not understand? How to build a macro? How to open VBA editor? What an event is? This is not appropriate venue for a tutorial on basics. If you need to learn coding there are introductory books and web sites.